# Having issues retrieving data from collection and subcollection of firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query and retreive a set of documents and subdocuments from firestore and store them in some custom objects I have created. The top collection maps to "Blockspaces" and the subcollection is "Blocks".

I can retrieve the top level collection without issue, but when I try to loop through the subcollection documents and store them in my top level object, nothing gets returned.

Here is the code that is doing the work. 
1. I retrieve the "blockspaces" data from top level collection.
2. for each document, I then get a reference to the sublevel collection ("blocks"), create it and add to top level object
3. Return the data.

```
     Future<List<Blockspace>> fetchBlockSpaces(String ownerId)  async {

List<Blockspace> blockspacesObjects = List<Blockspace>();

var query = Firestore.instance
    .collection("blockspaces")
    .where('users', arrayContains: ownerId);

   await query.getDocuments().then((blockspaces) {

      blockspaces.documents.forEach((blockspace) async {

         Blockspace b1 = Blockspace(
          blockSpaceId: blockspace.documentID,
          ownerId: blockspace.data['ownerId'],
           icon: blockspace.data['icon'],
          color: blockspace.data['color'],
           name: blockspace.data['name'],
          );

          List<Block> currentBlocks = List<Block>();
          QuerySnapshot blocks = await blockspace.reference.collection('blocks').getDocuments();
          blocks.documents.forEach((block) {
            Block block1 = Block(
            name: block.data['name'],
            color: block.data['color'],
            icon: block.data['icon'],
            // userPermissions: userRoles,
            ownerId: block.data['ownerId']);
            currentBlocks.add(block1);
          });
          b1.blocks = currentBlocks;
          blockspacesObjects.add(b1);
      }); 
   });

    return blockspacesObjects;
```

}

This seems like it should be really simple, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very difficult finding problem if you mix `await` with `then` (and `forEach`). Either use `await` completely or `then`, better not to mix (preferably avoid `then`). Please try with simplified code:

```
Future<List<Blockspace>> fetchBlockSpaces(String ownerId) async {
  final query = Firestore.instance
      .collection("blockspaces")
      .where('users', arrayContains: ownerId);

  final snapshot = await query.getDocuments();
  return Future.wait(snapshot.documents.map((bs) async {
    final blocksSnapshot =
        await bs.reference.collection('blocks').getDocuments();
    List<Block> currentBlocks = blocksSnapshot.documents.map((b) {
      return Block(
          name: b.data['name'],
          color: b.data['color'],
          icon: b.data['icon'],
          ownerId: b.data['ownerId']);
    }).toList();
    return Blockspace(
      blockSpaceId: bs.documentID,
      ownerId: bs.data['ownerId'],
      icon: bs.data['icon'],
      color: bs.data['color'],
      name: bs.data['name'],
      blocks: currentBlocks,
    );
  }));
}
```

Comment: I tried copying your code, the editor gives this error : The return type 'List<Future<Blockspace>>' isn't a 'Future<List<Blockspace>>', as defined by the method 'fetchBlockSpaces'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)